# jQuery - binding multiple events on input fields

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery

I was wondering if binding a single `change()` event on form fields is enough to correctly perform a action when the value of the field changes.

Or should I bind all possible events? like this:

```
    $(this).bind('change keyup focus click keydown', function(){
       // ...
    }).change();
```

Also, does binding multiple events affect performance?

Comment: Well, some events are not raised when the value is changed. E.g. `focus` or `click` are not raised when the value changes in a text field and if you click on a text field, it does not change the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`change` will only fire when the field loses focus (for most inputs).  If you want something a little more real time, use the HTML 5 `oninput` event.  This will pretty much catch any type of value change for an input element (and it bubbles, too!).  It's not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and lower, though, but [I wrote a plugin](http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event) that maps to `onpropertychange` for those browsers.

See also:

- [Effectively detecting user input in JavaScript](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript)

For the performance side of things, each event you described fires at different times so performance shouldn't be an issue unless.

Comment: but it doesn't work.. is it because I have the xhtml doctype?

Comment: ok, i used `input` instead of `oninput` like in the link you posted and it works :D

Comment: but you have to use it with change like `bind('change keyup')`, othewise checkboxes and selects won't work

Comment: @Alexandra: the `input` event should fire with `<select>` elements, which browser have you tested it with?  I wouldn't recommend the `keyup` event for input detection, stick to `change` or `click`.

Comment: chrome. input only fires on text elements, but it's ok because with input & change you can replace focus,click,keyup,etc.. (ps i meant `bind('change input')` in the comment above)

Comment: @Alexandra: that's odd, I guess a bug should be filed with Chrome.  The specification says that any element that offers the change event should also have an input event. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-forms/current-work/#the-change.  Edit: I just checked and Firefox doesn't support it for select elements either, but Opera does.  Not sure about IE 9.  Just be aware that both events might fire :-)

Answer (score 2):

Only listening to the `change` event *might* be sufficient for you (see also [@Andy E's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852650/jquery-binding-multiple-events-on-input-fields/4852726#4852726)). From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no performance penalty, unless you do something very slow in handler.

Answer (score 1):

Each event happens at a different time. There may be some overlap however depending on what you are doing they may be very different. For example a `keyup` event happens after the value has already been updated on the `input`. Whereas the `keydown` happens before. This can enable you to stop a value from ever entering the textbox.

As far as performance goes, you are running code for five different events in this example. Compared to a single event. At least your code should differentiate the overlap between events.

Answer (score 1):

The problem doing this:

```
$(this).bind('change keyup focus click keydown', function(e) { // ...
```

is that you would have to figure out which event actually was fired, entering the event handler.

```
switch(e.type) {
    case 'change': {
        break;
    }
    case 'focus': {
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I would just bind a `change` event if that is enough for you. You're getting in a lot of trouble when doing stuff on all those events, because `click` fires before `change`, `focus` after `click` etc. etc. This hurts to figure out and act properly.